# Let the tableView delete swipe delete items from NSUserDefaults - How to bring these two functions together?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, nsuserdefaults

*I want to let the user of my App delete items from the NSUserDefaults out of a tableView by swiping left on the Cell and press "delete". I know both function but I don't know how to bring them together in the right was so that the "remove swipe" affects the variable in NSUserDefaults. Maybe someone can help me out. Thank you.*

**This function should allow the User to access the delete Button in a tableView:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) 
}
```

**and the function should remove items from NSUserDefaults:**

```
@IBAction func deleteItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var itemListArray:NSMutableArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as NSMutableArray

    var mutableItemList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for dict:AnyObject in itemListArray{
        mutableItemList.addObject(dict as NSDictionary)
    }

    mutableItemList.removeObject(toDoData)

    userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
    userDefaults.setObject(mutableItemList, forKey: "itemList")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's change mutableItemList to an instance variable, which we'll use as the table's data source.  Or, you can create a new instance variable and set it accordingly.

```
var mutableItemList: NSMutableArray!
```

Then, to delete we call the `deleteItem` function.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        self.deleteItem(mutableItemList[indexPath.row])
        // show fancy fade animation to remove the cell from the table view
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

You can also simplify the `deleteItem` function.  You don't need to rebuild the array and remove the object from `NSUserDefaults`.  You can just delete the object and then set the updated array, which overwrites whatever was there.

```
func deleteItem(sender: AnyObject) {        
    mutableItemList.removeObject(sender)

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()        
    userDefaults.setObject(mutableItemList, forKey: "itemList")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```